# how to check framework availability in os x?

Tags: swift, bash, macos

How I can check in swift 3 (or in bash) that required framework was installed or not? In particular I want to be sure that OSXFUSE is available in OS. (In my OS it it was installed into /Library/Frameworks/OSXFUSE.framework )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for exist like this:

```
func isFUSEFrameworkAvailable() -> Bool {
    return (NSClassFromString("GMFinderInfo") != nil)
}
```

Don't forget mark OSXFUSE.framework as Optional
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In bash it is possible to call `system_profiler -detailLevel mini SPFrameworksDataType` and obtain next output:

```
OSXFUSE:

  Version: 3.6.0
  Obtained from: Identified Developer
  Last Modified: 7/4/17, 05:31
  Kind: Universal
  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
  Signed by: Developer ID Application: Benjamin Fleischer (3T5GSNBU6W), Developer ID Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
  Get Info String: OSXFUSE Framework
  Location: /Library/Frameworks/OSXFUSE.framework
  Private: No
```

Or even call it with `-xml` param and parse it in python script...